# java : Why the above condition is not being executed?

Tags: java

Hi the below is my program , could you please tell me why the first condition is ot being executed ??

```
  package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<String> values = null;

        String Id = "1234";

        if (values != null && Id != null && values.size() > 1
                && !values.contains(Id)) {
// This is never executed
            System.out.println("Throw Exception");

        } else {
// This is always called
            System.out.println("Fine");

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always end up in the `else` case, because `values` is `null` and your `if` condition needs `values != null`.

Maybe you should have a look at basic [Boolean Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) to understand why the `if` condition cannot be `true` in your case.

Comment: I need to check both conditions

Comment: @PreethiJain You connect your conditions with `&&`, so if one is `false`, the whole `if` condition is `false`...

Comment: Thanks , so you mean to say that , if one case / condition is false (null check in this case ) , it will not check the remaining ones ??

Comment: @PreethiJain If you use `&&` yes! Java is intelligent enough to see that one `false` condition suffices for the whole `if` condition to be `false`. The conditions will be checked from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Um:

```
List<String> values = null;
```

and

```
if (values != null && ...
```

How do you expect the code on the `if` branch to execute?

I think you meant:

```
    if (values != null && Id != null && values.size() > 1
            && !values.contains(Id)) {
        System.out.println("Fine");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Throw Exception");
    }
```

such that if all the checks hold then you are "fine", otherwise there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

values is `NULL`. So Only `ELSE` part will be executed.
So what is the question here actually?

I Think this is what you want actually

package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<String> values = null;
        String Id = "1234";

        // Some modification to values 

        if (values == null || Id == null || (values.size() > 1
                && !values.contains(Id))) {
            System.out.println("Throw Exception");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fine");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As  values  is null   and you are checking values is not null then it will execute always else block

```
List<String> values = null;

                String Id = "1234";

                if (values != null && Id != null && !values.contains(Id)) {
        // This is never executed
                    System.out.println("Throw Exception");

                } else {
        // This is always called
                    System.out.println("Fine");

                }
```

Comment: This will quickly give you a NullPointerException at the `values.size() > 1` condition

Comment: when you will check values  not null ,it will execute else block.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute your conditions then create data according to condition

```
 List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    values.add("12345");
    values.add("12345");
```

And -1 for not putting enough efforts before posting on SO

Answer (score 0):

in java we use:

```
String test = "";
String test2 = "";

if(test.equal(test2)){
//something
}
else{
//something
}
```

in C# we use:

```
String test = "";
String test2 = "";

if(test == test2){
//something
}
else{
//something
}
```

to compare strings.. hope this helps . :D